# Create Enum with list of the same object

Tags: java, list, enums

I would like to create an enum containing one attribut, a list of objects extending the same interface or the same abstract class.
The objective is to have a loop on each list of my enum to call methods dynamically.

```
public interface Regles {
    void verifier();
}

public class Regle01 implements Regles {
    @Override
    public void verifier() {
    }
}

public class Regle02 implements Regles {
    @Override
    public void verifier() {
    }
}

public enum ListRegles {
    ENUM1(Arrays.asList(new Regle01(), new Regle02())),
    ENUM2(Arrays.asList(new Regle01()))

    private List<Regles> regles = new ArrayList<Regles>();

    ListRegles(List<Regles> r) {
        regles = r;
    }
}
```

how can i do this please ?

Answer (score 4):

enum:

```
public enum ListRegles {
    ENUM1(new Regle01(),new Regle02()),
    ENUM2(new Regle01());

    private List<Regles> regles ;

    ListRegles(Regles... regles) {
        this.regles = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(regles));
    }

    public void verify() {
        for (Regles regle : regles) {
            regle.verifier();
        }
    }
}
```

Will call verifier for Regle01 and Regle02

```
ListRegles.ENUM1.verify();
```